# Mimicking DB's schema in EF in Core 3 using C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In a database first application, I have a lot of tables under several schemas in the database, Lookup-tables and/or tables for a specific departments (or group of people). I am using C# under .NET Core 3; trying to group the tables in similar schemas in the application code but I can't find any suitable solution.

For example: In my database, there are 80 tables in lookup schema. In the c# code I want to be able to access these in a similar way, e.g. `dbcontext.lookup.Tablexxx...` or for marketing summary, `dbcontext.marketing.summaryxxx` etc. Is this possible? Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could intrododuce a nested class in your DbContext to hold the DbSet.  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tablexxx>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public class Lookup
    {
        Db db;
        public Lookup(Db db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
        public DbSet<Tablexxx> CreditAccounts => db.Set<Tablexxx>();
    }
    public Lookup Lookups => new Lookup(this);
```